# Warning: require(/wp-admin/wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /wp-admin/index.php on line 17

Tags: wordpress

I found this error in my wordpress site

Warning: require(/home/cjstech/public_html/wp-admin/wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cjstech/public_html/wp-admin/index.php on line 17

I will gladly appreciate anyone who has some knowledge about how to fix this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the index.php file as below to resolve this issue, only if you are running WordPress installation from the root directory. You just need to change the following lines:

Require ('. /wp-blog-header.php');

To this:

Require ('wp-blog-header.php');

Comment: Raina I have require with this.                                                         
      require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

Comment: Yes, I know this is required. Please remove ' / ' and try again. I think it will fix your problem.

Comment: I am running WP in subfolder as it is a multi-lingual website.  However, without moving the wp site from its subfolder, and keeping the index.php file in the subfolder (as the direction was done through .htaccess file) I had to keep the slash as in the first example.  I had my troubles.  Although your reply worked backwards for me, it did help in resolving my problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I can see this error is in wp-admin flolder, Where normally developer din't make any changes.

According to wordpress rule, avoid over writing the wp-admin and wp-include folder files. Because the changers in this folder (like: wp-admin, wp-includes) exist till the wordpress in not updated. 
**So, It means your application is not secure and any virus or hacking is effecting your application.**

**Solution:**

**Temporary:** Download any wordpress version in your local system or open any existing wordpress in you system and go to wp-admin/index.php file and copy the whole code and paste the code in your application at the same location( wp-admin/index.php).

**Permanent:** Clean your code and file's in you hosting.

**Note:** if you have multiple application running in your hosting then clean all the application